# Multiplying a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a matrix

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix. I am interested in the following construction: define the measure $A\mu$ by $A\mu(C)=\mu(AC)$, where $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A C = \{A c: c\in C\}$. Has this been used in literature before?

Comment: Presumably you mean $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$? For the Lebesgue measure, $A\mu(C) = a\cdot \mu(C)$ for a constant $a$ (that depends on $A$ but not on $C$), and this constant is called the (unsigned) determinant of $A$.

Comment: @Arthur yes I did, thank you for spotting that typo! That is a nice example too -- I am more general setting however, and whether there is an expression we can write for a general $\mu$

Comment: There is no general expression (for this kind of transformation) for a general $\mu$ and a general $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^n$. Compare, for instance, the case of Lebesgue measure with the case of the counting measure.